# Move mail input to mail app

Tags: java, android

I have problem with my code afther the user put his email I want thet afther I push "send mail button" it will send the mail to the user input.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (btnMail == v) {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String mail = intent.getExtras().getString("Mail");
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.setType("text/plain");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,mail);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "invite from my app");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this my new app");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Email"));
    }
    else if (btnAdress==v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:19.076,72.8777"));
            Intent chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Launch Map");
            startActivity(chooser);
    }
}
```

[image: first activity]

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (btSand==v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",etName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Mail",etMail.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[image: seconf activity]

Answer (score 0):

ok ty i manage to find the answer

if somone want its :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (btnMail == v) {
        String []emails = {MainActivity.SendMail};


        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.setType("text/plain");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emails);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "invite from my app");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this my new app");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Email"));
```